# Show that $\mathrm{rank}(I_n-A^TA)-\mathrm{rank}(I_m-AA^T) \geq n-m.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> For any $m×n$ matrix $A$, where $n>m$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m,$ show that $$\mathrm{rank}(I_n-A^TA)-\mathrm{rank}(I_m-AA^T) \geq n-m$$

---

Using the hint by Omnomnomnom, I've known that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues with the same geometric multiplicity when they are both square.

It seems that I should consider geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $1$ of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$, but I couldn't see how to make it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It suffices to note that $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ will have non-zero eigenvalues with the same geometric multiplicity

Comment: This follows from a general result: $$\mathrm{rank}(I_m-AB)+n=\mathrm{rank}(I_n-BA)+m,$$ where $A,B$ are $m\times n$, respectively $n\times m$ matrices. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548704/121097).

Answer (score 3):

By the rank-nullity theorem, we have $$ \dim \ker (I_n -A^t A)=n-\mathrm{rank}(I_n-A^tA),$$
so your question is equivalent to showing that $$\dim \ker (I_n -A^t A)\leq\dim \ker (I_m -A A^t).$$
First notice that (as in the hint above), if $ v \in \ker (I_n -A^t A)$ then $Av\in\ker (I_m -A A^t)$.

Next, let $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ (possibly $k=0$) be a basis of $\ker (I_n -A^t A)$. You need to show that $Av_1,\ldots ,Av_k$ are linearly independent in $\ker (I_n -A A^t)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: To show that the vectors $Av_j$ are linearly independent, it suffices to now that the matrix $A^T$ maps them to a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $A^TAv = v$ for some vector $v$, then $(AA^T)A v = Av$. That is: if $v$ is in the nullspace of $I - A^TA$, then $Av$ is in the nullspace of $I - AA^T$.